# How to find out who caused the window.onbeforeunload(): F5 or submit?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I work on a small web app and I need to show confirm dialog after user refreshes his browser. I do it using `window.onbeforeunload = function() { ...}`. The problem is that it is invoked not only on refreshes but after submits as well. I have a question: can I find out somehow if `window.onbeforeunload` was caused by refresh or by a submit element?

Comment: Note that the two options you mentioned aren't the only two ways that an `onbeforeunload` can be triggered.

Comment: I just want to show confirm dialog only of F5s - not submits

Comment: So add a submit event handler that removes the beforeunload handler.

Comment: Do I remove by `window.onbeforeunload=null`?

Answer (score 0):

You can write event handlers for various events that would navigate you away from the page and have an identifier to manage state. Then you can use this identifier in onbeforepageunload function to do whatever action you want to perform. Here is a code example that looks for input type submit and sets the identifier. Similarly you can have one for anchor tags and so on.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>

</head>
<body>
<form action="">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
  <script>
    var submit_was_clicked = false;

    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (event) {
      if(submit_was_clicked){
        console.log('submit button clicked')
      }else{
        console.log('on before unload');
      }
    });

    document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      if (e.target.type.toLowerCase() === 'submit') {
          submit_was_clicked = true;
      }
    }, true);
  </script>
</html>
```